# Schedule a job at a specific time from code in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I am using Parse.com backend for my application and I need to perform a particular job at a specific time and notify the mobile app via Push notification.

I cannot find a way to do it from code. I see we can only schedule jobs in Parse using its UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution is to have a job that runs every 5 minutes, checking for a record that's due to be processed and comparing the time to now. If it is due then do the work and send the notification, marking the job as done (or just deleting the record depending on your needs).